# contenteditableのdivタグにて、Range APを用いてキーを押下した際にカーソルが一番後ろの判断する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript

contenteditableのdivタグにて、Range APを用いてキーボードを押下した際に、カーソルが一番後ろの場合の判定する仕方が分からず質問させていただきました。

もしくは他になにかいい方法があればご教授いただけますでしょうか。

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="proseMirror">
    <p>123<br>56<br>7abc</p>
</div>
```

上記のようにカーソルが `<p>123<br>56<br>7abc[ここ]</p>` の場合の判定方法が知りたいです

**JavaScript**

```
$('#proseMirror').on('keydown', function(e) {

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    console.log("★★★★★★★★")

    console.log("focusOffset:"+selection.focusOffset);
    console.log("rangeCount:"+selection.rangeCount);
    console.log("focusNode:"+selection.focusNode):
    console.log("range endContainer:"+range.endContainer.lastChild);
    console.log("1:"+range.endContainer.nextSibling);
    console.log("2:"+range.endContainer.lastChild);
    console.log("3:"+range.endContainer.textContent);
    console.log("4:"+range.endContainer.previousSibling);
    console.log("5:"+range.endContainer.selectionStart);
    console.log("6:"+range.endContainer.selectionEnd);

    console.log("★★★★★★★★")
});
```

Comment: `<p>123<br>56<br>7abc</p>[ここ]` の場合はどうしたいでしょうか

Comment: 文字列の最後尾にある際に、entryキーを押下した場合<br><br>を二ついれて
entryキーを2回押さなければならない事象を解消させようと考えています。